# Android:Purpose of getTag() and setTag() in View Class

Tags: android, android-view

```
public void setTag(final Object tag) {
                mTag = tag;
}
public Object getTag() {
            return mTag;
}
```

These are two methods from View Class in Android.
Following is the official documentation of these two methods respectively.

```
 /**
     * Returns this view's tag.
     *
     * @return the Object stored in this view as a tag
     *
     * @see #setTag(Object)
     * @see #getTag(int)


        */
 /**
     * Sets the tag associated with this view. A tag can be used to mark
     * a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the
     * hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within a view without
     * resorting to another data structure.
     *
     * @param tag an Object to tag the view with
     *
     * @see #getTag()
     * @see #setTag(int, Object)
     */
```

tag functions are used extensively in baseadapter implementation but I couldn't understand its purpose and how to use them. Can you please explain this some good example to help me understand the role of these functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of it as as plainly simple as it's possible - a "tag".

What does a grocery shop product tag tell you?
Basically a lot of things, such as name, price, origin country, discount, and many others.

Imagine you're making an application that displays such products in a grid using ImageView's.
How to easily determine the product features from the ImageView? Tagging it is one of the possible solutions.

```
class Product {

    String mName;
    String mManufacturer;
    String mOriginCountry;

    double mPrice;
    int mDiscount;

    int mImageId; // A reference to a drawable item id
}

[...]

class My Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        [...] // Some code

        // Grab the imageView reference and grab (or create) the tag for it
        ImageView someItemView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.some_product_view);
        Product someProductTag = new Product( ... some data ...);

        // Add the tag to the ImageView
        someItemView.addTag(someProductTag);
    }

    private void displayItemInfo(ImageView iv) {

        // Grab the tag and display the info.
        String productName = ((Product)iv.getTag()).mName();
        Toast.show(mContext, "This is " + productName, Toast.LONG).show(); 

    }

}
```

Of course this is **very** simplified. Ideally you would have an adapter which would create the view basing on your provided tags, or would create your tags automatically.

I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 3):

A good example is the View Holder pattern. An implementation can be found in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on ListViews.

> The View Holder pattern allows to avoid the findViewById() method in the adapter.
>
> A ViewHolder class is a static inner class in your adapter which holds references to the relevant views. in your layout. This reference is assigned to the row view as a tag via the setTag() method.
>
> If we receive a convertView object, we can get the instance of the ViewHolder via the getTag() method and assign the new attributes to the views via the ViewHolder reference.
>
> While this sounds complex this is approximately 15 % faster then using the findViewById() method.

The example

> The following code shows a performance optimized adapter implementation which reuses existing views and implements the holder pattern.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyPerformanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Activity context;
  private final String[] names;

  static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
  }

  public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
          .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
        || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are just a way to attach an `Object` to the View.
In BaseAdapter, it is used to store view ids to avoid the expensive `findViewById` operation each time the system request a view.

Answer (score 1):

The Tag field is a good way to store your own state information for any view class. One use is to store the position of a view in a `ListView`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24214482/1270276) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

`setTag(int, object)` is very useful for storing a custom class to a view. Here is my implementation :

```
 itemView.setTag(R.id.food_tag, food);
```

The variable food is an instance of custom object Food. The key for setTag should always be a resource id.

I could retrieve this Custom object this way in the `OnClickListener()`:

```
Food selectedFood = (Food) view.getTag(R.id.food_tag);
```